# How I can ignore PathVariable conditionally on swagger ui using springdoc openapi

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I am migrating from springfox 2.9.0 to springdoc-openapi-ui 1.2.33.
I have a requirement to show or hide the PathVariable on swagger ui based on condition.
I have two paths like below

1. String nameIdentifier = "{fisrtName}/{lastName}"
2. String nameIdentifier = "{fisrtName}"

I am passing one of the above nameIdentifier based on the requirement.

I am using a single controller for the above paths as shown below

```
@GetMapping(path = "persons/${nameIdentifier}/display")
public List<Person> getPersons(@PathVariable String fisrtName,
    @IgnoreLastName @PathVariable Optional<String> lastName) {

}
```

In springfox I was able to achieve it using `docket.ignoredParameterTypes(IgnoreLastName.class)` as shown below.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {

    Docket docket;

    docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()                
     .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("go.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());

        if (!nameIdentifier.contains("lastName")) {
            docket.ignoredParameterTypes(IgnoreLastName.class);
        }
        return docket;
    }
```

But in springdoc open api I am unable to achieve the same.
Your help appreciated in the same.
Coding is done in java

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@Hidden` swagger annotations or `@Parameter(hidden = true)`.

If you can not pass on parameter level, you can set it globally: You will need to upgrade to v1.3.0 of springdoc-openapi-ui.

```
static {
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addAnnotationsToIgnore(IgnoreLastName.class);
}
```

Comment: We can not pass value to hidden programatically **@Parameter(hidden = true/false(based on condition))**

Comment: Use:  SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addAnnotationsToIgnore(IgnoreLastName.class) with v1.2.34

Comment: Hi, @brianbro thanks for your time and solution.
I have tried adding the above solution but it is not working as expected.
```
static String nameIdentifier  = "/{fisrtName}";

 static {
  if (!nameIdentifier.contains("lastName")) {
   SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addAnnotationsToIgnore(IgnoreLastName .class);
  }
 }
```

but still, it showing lastName in Parameters section on swagger ui as mandatory parameter and not hiding it.

I have tried adding above code to my configuration class

Comment: Hi @Shilanand, I have updated to the right version: v1.3.0. With this version PathVariable can also be ignored if they have the right annotation. For example; SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addAnnotationsToIgnore(IgnoreLastName.class)

Comment: Hi, brianbro
Thank you very much for your solution and this is what I was looking for. vote up.

brianbro if you have release notes link can you provide the same.

Comment: Found the release notes link https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/releases